# how to hide sms notification when flutter app is open ?

Tags: flutter

I tried to know how to hide the pop up sms notification when my flutter app is open, and if possible only for one specifique number. Not a black list, the sms need to be listenable after with the original sms app, but just no visible when he is received. Thank you